# Google installer has stopped working

Tags: installer

Several times a day I get "Google installer has stopped working" I tried a virus scanner and Malwarebyte but the message still keeps to came back.Is there a way to get rid of this prompt?

Answer (score 0):

Use the System Tray to remove Notifications. A great way to disable pop ups of this kind is disabling Google Updater in the list of your Programs that start at Start Time.

You should find the Menu that would allow to modify those settings through task manager.